# How to set toolbar title from fragment using Navigation UI Component

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-titlebar, android-components

I have an activity with a toolbar from a default layout in Android Studio and I can easily change the title in the toolbar through the following method:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("toolbarTitle", "A new title");

    NavHostFragment
        .findNavController(this)
        .navigate(R.id.action_navigation_conversation_to_placeholder, bundle);
```

Where safe args is already implemented for `toolbarTitle` in the navigation menu layout.

However now I am trying to change the title from the fragment that is opened via the method above, for example;

- MyActivity ->opens-> MyFragment
- MyFragment changes title

I do know how to update it without using Navigation UI Components, but I want to use them if it is possible.

Other similar questions are only related to the example I already provided above for when a new fragment is being opened or by suggesting the use of the typical method that does not make use of the Navigation UI Components, none cover this specific scenario.

Comment: So you're trying to change the toolbar title when you navigate to the new destination? Is this a fixed title that is always the same for that destination or something more dynamic?

Comment: It's a dynamic title that is to be set from the fragment that is opened, otherwise I would've just set the label directly in the navigation menu layout

Comment: An example that can clarify the above is a title made out of a list of users currently in a chat (fragment) and those users can leave or join, thus changing the title when that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is not possible with the only way to achieve this by doing it directly without using the Navigation Architecture Components.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the the title by accesing the supportActionBar from the activity:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Your Title"
}
```